# Tensor power of a quotient space

Tags: tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, quotient-spaces

Let $E$ and $F$ be vector spaces, $F$ a subspace of $E$. Is there any canonical isomorphism between
$E/F \otimes E/F$ and a quotient of the form $E \otimes E/G$, where $G$ is a subspace of $E \otimes E$ depending only on $F$ and $E$ ?

Also, what if we use symmetric tensor products ?

Comment: Your $F$ must be a subspace of $E$ (not just a mere vector space). Let's suppose $E$ is finite-dimensional with dimension $n$, and let $F$ have dimension $m$ and the mysterious $G$ have dimension $d$.  Then $(E/F) \otimes (E/F)$ has dimension $(n-m)^2$ while $(E \otimes E)/G$ has dimension $n^2 - d$. So $(n-m)^2 = n^2 - d$, which means $d = 2mn - m^2 = m(2n-m)$.  Since the dimension of $G$ is not purely determined by that of $F$, but depends on the dimension of the larger space $E$, what do you think?

Comment: I formulated the problem poorly. I meant $G$ depends only on $E$ and $F$ (something like $E \otimes F + F \otimes E + F \otimes F$ for example)

Comment: The natural reduction map $f \colon E \rightarrow E/F$ is surjective, so the linear map $f \otimes f \colon E \otimes E \rightarrow (E/F) \otimes (E/F)$, where $(f \otimes f)(v \otimes w) = f(v) \otimes f(w)$ on elementary tensors, is surjective. Let $G$ be the kernel of $f \otimes f$. It certainly is determined by $E$ and $F$ because that's the only information you in the problem at the beginning.

Comment: Yes, and I just realized that $G$ is precisely $E \otimes F + F \otimes E$. The count of dimension is correct because the sum is not direct and the intersection is $F \otimes F$

Comment: See Theorem 2.19 and Theorem 5.5 in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf.